# oracle plsql to_date format to mm-dd-yyy

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT check_date
FROM check_header;
```

Which returns me  3/14/2014 3:24:08 PM

but I need to format this to MM-dd-yy and should be returned as 03-14-14

I tried this:

```
 SELECT to_date(check_date,'MM-dd-yy')
             From check_header;
```

but it is giving me a error invalid month

Comment: `TO_DATE()` converts to **date**. You want to convert to **string**.

Comment: Is `check_date` a column of type `date`?  Or is it a column of type `varchar2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `to_char()`:

```
SELECT to_char(check_date,'MM-dd-yy') From check_header;
```

Comment: Assuming that `check_date` is actually of `DATE` type. The OP did not consider it a relevant piece of info ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `to_char` instead of `to_date`:

```
SELECT to_char(check_date,'MM-dd-yy') from check_header;
```

`to_date` converts a string into Oracle's internal date representation, which is then displayed according to your NLS settings.

`to_char` converts from Oracle's internal date representation to a string using the format you specify.